# How to remove outer line border of QLineEdit of PyQt or PySide2?

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2, qlineedit

How to remove the outer blue border ? thank you!

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 100, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit:focus { border-radius: 5px; border:1px solid  #c6255e;}"); 

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.resize(200, 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, the format is a little mess

Comment: @Chans try with: `self.lineEdit.setFrame(False)`

Comment: @eyllanesc this didn't work

Comment: @Chans It seems to me that it is more a problem with the style, for example I use the fusion style and I do not see that problem, what is the output of `print(app.style().metaObject().className())`? try with: `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah, the fusion style worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can call `lineEdit.setAttribute(Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)`.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer, explaining why it addresses the original question? That will help anybody else who searches for this particular problem and wants to learn more.